# Calculating the average power dissipated in an AC circuit

Tags: ac

This is the question from a very important assignment I am working on: "A load is being driven by an AC source. At a particular time, the voltage across the load is 120cos(wt+50) and the current through the load is 20sin(wt-10). Calculate the average power in Watts dissipated by the load."

My working:
I first convert the current into cosine to give 20cos(wt-100)

Then I use the formula \$\ P=|Vrms||Irms|cos(\theta v -\theta i)\$
which gives me -1039.2 W

I assumed that the question asked for real power since it is the power dissipated in the resistor and thats the only equation the literature gave.
 An online calculator gave me a complex number with the real part twice the value that I found. Is this correct? Negative power in a resistor? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An online calculator gave me a complex number with the real part twice the value that I found.

Be careful with online calculators and the inputs they expect. Many AC formulas expect RMS values.

Assuming the voltage and current given in your problem are *not* RMS, you've done it right.

$$
P_{avg} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} V_o \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} I_o \cos{150}
\\
P_{avg} = \frac{120 \cdot 20}{2} * \hspace{2pt} \text{-}.866 \\
P_{avg} = - 1039.2 \hspace{2pt} \text{W}
$$

Answer (score 2):

> Negative power in a resistor? Where did I go wrong?

The load is not a resistor. If it were a resistor, there would be no phase difference between the current and voltage waveforms.

In general, a negative power is possible --- it means the load has a power source within it and it is delivering power back to your source rather than taking power from it.

So I don't think you have approached the problem incorrectly.

Comment: Then the average power would be zero?

Comment: Just because it's not a resistor doesn't mean it's just a network or capacitors and inductors. It could be the mains. It could be some machinery. It could be another generator.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you wrote the given information we have:

$$\text{P}=\frac{\hat{\text{V}}_{\space\text{load}}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{I}}_{\space\text{load}}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\cos\left(\varphi_{\space\text{load}}\right)\tag1$$

Where:

$$\varphi_{\space\text{load}}=\left|\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\space\text{load}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\space\text{load}}\right)\right|\tag2$$

Using the given values we get:

1. $$\hat{\text{V}}_{\space\text{load}}=120\tag3$$
2. $$\hat{\text{I}}_{\space\text{load}}=20\tag4$$
3. $$\varphi_{\space\text{load}}=\left|\arg\left(120e^{\frac{50\pi i}{180}}\right)-\arg\left(20e^{-\frac{5\pi i}{9}}\right)\right|=\frac{5\pi}{6}\tag5$$

So:

$$\text{P}=\frac{120}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{20}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)=-600\sqrt{3}\approx-1039.23048\space\text{W}\tag6$$

Answer (score 0):

In calculation of complex power the real part of the complex power represent the average power dissipated.
S=P+jQ
P=Vrms*Irms*cos(Φ)
where cosΦ is power factor of the circuit hence the calculations may be easy.